# 'Unhandled stream error in pipe' adding iOS platform to PhoneGap 3

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to build a new Phonegap 3.0 app via the CLI

When I execute

```
phonegap run ios --V
```

I get the following output

```
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] Checking iOS requirements...
[phonegap] Running "xcodebuild -version" (output to follow)
[phonegap] Xcode 5.0 Build version 5A1413
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the iOS platform...
[warning] missing library cordova/ios/3.0.0
[phonegap] downloading https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git;a=snapshot;h=3.0.0;sf=tgz...
[phonegap] Requesting {"uri":"https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git;a=snapshot;h=3.0.0;sf=tgz"}...

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib._binding.onerror (zlib.js:295:17)
```

It also results in an empty directory being created at ~/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.0.0/ which requires me to rm -rf the same before I continue or I get a whole different error...

Calling the same URL in a browser results in a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to bee that its an invalid or broken url for the cordova lib.

If you cant wait for it to work or the phonegap lib gets updated you could modify the following file

```
<location to phonegap node module>/node_modules/cordova/platforms.js
```

Change version attribute to 3.1.0-rc1, e.g

```
{
parser : require('./src/metadata/ios_parser'),
url    : 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git',
version: '3.1.0-rc1'
},
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've modified the value for version in platform.js. 

Phonegap is still trying to download "missing library cordova/ios/3.0.0" so it may be either 
a. also getting that value from elsewhere or 
b. need to be refreshed. 

A reboot has made no difference.

Further suggestions appreciated… (or I may have to wait until somebody at PG fixes it…)

Comment: Are you sure you changed to correct platform.js file. I guess you could install cordova, "npm install -g cordova" and change that platform.js file and "run cordova add platform ios"

Comment: There is an issue open here that you could follow. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/170

Comment: I've triple checked, rebooted, scoured my machine for instances of platform.js. I've also tried arbitrarily changing the filename to something else. All are ignored. Frustrating...

Comment: Wow. Found it using terminal. Wasn't showing up in a spotlight search. Location was /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/ had to sudo vi to edit as the file was locked. seems to be working now...

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just ran into the same issue with 'cordova platform add ios'. Martinj's suggestion (editing platforms.js) did the trick for me.